# Change File Name to Folder Name

Tags: file, batch-file

I've been working on a batch script (.bat) to change file name to the same folder name 3 levels up but no luck. I can only get it to rename 1 level up. There are multiple files in multiple folders.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't completely understand the intent of your current code. But the following will rename a given file based on the folder 3 levels up. Note that you can only rename one file with a given extension per folder using this strategy.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "file=H:\Techs\Exported Videos\Scenario\1-CAS IED\Media player format\A8 West\abc.avi"
for %%A in ("%file%") do for %%B in ("%%~A\..\..\..") do ren "%%~A" "%%~nxB%%~xA"
```

Note that I include the extension of the folder name because folder names can include dots.

**EDIT**

Based on OP's comments, I believe the following will properly rename all relevant .avi files. The code has been tested, and works in my hands. Simply set the `root` and `files` values as appropriate.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "root=H:\Techs\Exported Videos\Scenario"
set "files=*.avi"

for %%A in ("%root%\.") do set "root=%%~fA"
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /b /s /a-d "%root%\%files%"') do (
  for %%B in ("%%~A\..\..\..") do (
    if /i "%%~dpB" equ "%root%\" ren "%%~A" "%%~nxB%%~xA"
  )
)
```

Comment: dbenham, thanks for replying.  Okay, my current issue is this. I'm using the xProtect video software to capture training videos with multiple cameras. Once training is completed, I'll export all the selected videos from the xProtect to H:\Techs\Exported Videos\Scenario\. The software would export the videos (avi format) to the designated location but it would by default create "FileName\Media player format\Cam Name\VideoClip.avi" (I.e."1-CAS IED\Media player format\A8 West\abc.avi"). It would do this for all videos.

Comment: What I need the batch file to do is to rename all the .avi file to the original name given during export (I.e.1-CAS). So in other words the script would go up 3 folders up (from where the .avi file lives) and give the .avi file that folder's name. For example:"H:\Techs\Exported Videos\Scenario\1-CAS\Media player format\A8 West\abc.avi" to "H:\Techs\Exported Videos\Scenario\1-CAS\Media player format\A8 West\1-CAS.avi" or "H:\Techs\Exported Videos\Scenario\2-IED\Media player format\B1 East\abc.avi" to "H:\Techs\Exported Videos\Scenario\2-IED\Media player format\B1 East\2-IED.avi" etc)

Comment: @USMC-3537 - I've updated my answer to address your explanation.

Comment: I have tried your edited script but it's not working. Am I forgetting something? I want to execute it via batch file. Thanks again for your assistance

Comment: @USMC-3537 - OK, I reworked the script considerably and tested. It should work now. The prior version mostly worked for me, but there were some problems dealing with FOR reprocessing renamed files, as well as unwanted renaming of files at additional levels.

Comment: @dbenham- Your batch script works like a charm. Well written. Now let's say that I want to move all those renamed avi files to the Scenario folder after. Should I use the move command? Thank you again.

Comment: @USMC-3537 - You should have put that in your original question. You can rename and move all in one step: `move /y "%%~A" "%root%\%%~nxB%%~xA"`. Don't forget to accept an answer if you are happy with it.

Comment: Once again thank you. Everything works perfect.  By the way im new to this. Did I accept it correctly by hit the check mark? Or I need to write a nice comment in the profile?

Comment: @USMC-3537 - Yep, click the check mark - it's that easy. Only one answer per question can be accepted. You get 2 rep points for accepting. Once you reach 15 rep points, you can then up vote any answer you find helpful, even answers to other people's questions.

Answer (score 1):

you might try this:

```
@echo off &setlocal
set /a PathLevel=3
for %%a in (
    "H:\Techs\Exported Videos\Scenario\1-CAS IED\Media player format\A8 West\1-CAS IED.avi"
    "H:\Techs\Exported Videos\Scenario\2-SAF\Media player format\A8 PTZ\2-SAF.avi"
    ) do (
    call:doit "%%~a"
)
goto:eof

:doit
set "fname=%~1"
set /a cnt=0
for %%a in ("%fname:\=","%") do set /a cnt+=1
set /a cnt-=PathLevel
for %%a in ("%fname:\=","%") do (
    set /a cnt-=1
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    if !cnt! equ 0 (
        endlocal
        set "nname=%%~a"
    ) else endlocal
)
echo ren "%fname%" "%nname%%~x1"
goto:eof
```

---

output is:

```
ren "H:\Techs\Exported Videos\Scenario\1-CAS IED\Media player format\A8 West\1-CAS IED.avi" "1-CAS IED.avi"
ren "H:\Techs\Exported Videos\Scenario\2-SAF\Media player format\A8 PTZ\2-SAF.avi" "2-SAF.avi"
```

Comment: Nice script but please read my comment below for dbenham as it explain in better details my issue. Thank you.